# Stop Resharper from replacing variable when prepending method

Tags: resharper, code-completion

I have a line of code that looks like this...

```
Dim magicId as Int32 = data.Value("MagicId")
```

Where `data.Value("MagicId")` returns an object...

Now I want to prepend `Convert.ToInt32` so it looks like this...

```
Dim magicId as Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(data.Value("MagicId"))
```

But when I start typing right before the `data.Value("MagicId")` Resharper replaces the data giving me something like this.

```
Dim magicId as Int32 = Convert.Value("MagicId") '<--- WRONG
```

What's the setting to change this behavior?

Comment: Do you select an item from Intellisense list via Enter, Tab, Space, Insert or mouse button? Or are you just typing "Convert." and that's all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I press tab... So it's like Convert.ToIn<tab> on tab is when then variable gets overwritten.